# Is this answer considered to be spam?

Tags: support, spam

The OP have asked the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4975266/how-to-convert-html-to-doc-in-php/5293798#5293798) and [self-answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5293798/1805640) to it a month later. Here is OP answer:

> Here is the solution...
>
> http://www.phpdocx.com/

I have marked this answer as spam but my flag was declined. Why my spam flag was wrong in that place? What flag should I use? Does this answer considered to be a good answer in StackOverflow?

Comment: Not being the moderator who handled the flag I can't say for sure, but there's no evidence that the user is affiliated with the site they're linking to.

Comment: @ChrisF: If we would need to provide evidence that all the spamming users on SO are affiliated with whatever they spam for, then we should save everyone some time and remove the spam flag.

Comment: @PlasmaHH - if you think that something's spam then by all means flag it as such. However, don't be surprised or upset if the flag is declined. Accepting a spam flag has serious consequences for the flagged account so we *have* to be 100% sure that it is spam.

Comment: @PlasmaHH - In this case, it's also worth noting that we're talking about a 10k user leaving that answer, and they never mentioned that site anywhere else in any of their posts. If they're a spammer, they're *really* bad at it.

Comment: or... http://xkcd.com/810/  Mission Accomplished

Comment: The answer appears to be deleted now.

Comment: @ChrisF You *could* manually deem the flag "helpful" without letting it take effect and supply a message now.

Comment: @damry - marking a spam flag as helpful will leave the -1 on the post. If it's not spam then we don't want that.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That doesn't appear to be spam. The question was asked in 2011, so likely prior to the close as off topic for tool/library/recommendation close reason. However, that question should be closed now. *(already has 2 close votes, I'm all out of close votes or I'd vote)*. It should be closed obviously because it is looking for a library.

Users are free to leave their own answers and accept them. Yes, in some cases this can really seem quite shady if a new user asks a bad off topic question and leaves a link that appears to be promotional. In such cases, I'd recommend an other mod flag explaining the shady-ness.

There are still many hundreds if not thousands of open questions that need to be closed for this same off topic tool/library reason. So if you see them, please vote to close or flag to close if not 3k rep yet.  But don't go marking most any of the answers as spam, since most of them are an answer to the bad off topic question.